# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4 - Python

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, wkt

I'm having trouble while trying to create polygon using the **shapely** library in python.

```
[testPolygon(polygonShape) for polygonShape in fileAppender]
```

and the testPolygon function is defined as:

```
def testPolygon(polygonShape): 
    if shapely.wkt.loads(polygonShape).is_valid:
        print("great")
```

but I'm having this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4
```

Is there anyway to check if the string object (polygonShape) is a valid polygon before parse it? Or even better, if it's possible to correct this corrupt polygon?

Answer (score 2):

Your LineString wkt is likely containing a geometry that is not a valid polygon. For example:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Polygon
>>> from shapely.wkt import loads

>>> wkt = 'LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1, 0 0)'
>>> poly = Polygon(loads(wkt).coords)
```

As you can see the LineString does start and end at the same vertex and has multiple edges, but it doesn't make it a polygon since you only have 3 points, i.e. "Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3":

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4
Shell is not a LinearRing
```

but `poly` is still an object of type Polygon

```
>>> type(poly)
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

so you can check if it's a valid polygon by:

```
>>> poly.is_empty
True
```

Why would you want to check if it's a valid polygon this way? Because `IllegalArgumentException` is NOT an actual exception as in you can't catch it with `try/except`. I don't know why. I hope someone in the comments knows.